# OpenMP performance profiling

Tags: multithreading, openmp, performance-testing

I have written a code which has multiple loops parallelized using OpenMP. When a single instance of this code is executed, the run time is quite low. But when I execute multiple instances of the code in parallel, then the run time for each instance is way higher than expected.

Using Zoom, I profiled a single instance (when 70 were running in parallel), and the profile shows that 65% of the time is consumed by OpenMP (please see the image below). Could that be correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've [oversubscribed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/archive/2009/12/01/oversubscription-a-classic-parallel-performance-problem.aspx) the machine. Thus OpenMP runtime starts wasting time in spin-loops waiting for the threads which are [preempted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29). Even if the spin-loops are oversubscription-aware (i.e. call to `sched_yield()` periodically), it still wastes time for frequent context switches and other overheads.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the possible solution could be? And how I could see the spent in context switching?

Comment: there is only one solution - just do not create so many threads and so many processes. Ask separate questions if needed - how to achieve what you tried to achieve or may google help you - I gave you the keywords

Comment: @user1274878, to tell the truth, it is not clear what exactly you try to ask. Do you ask why 70 multithreaded processes oversubscribe the machine? Or how you may run 70 processes and do not oversubscribe the machine? Could you explain what you try to achieve? And why do you really need to run a lot of multithreaded process simultaneously?